# Why can't I set the index value of the loop algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm, loops

So, basically I am practicing some algorithms. And I am trying to figure out why the following code is giving me an error when I try to set the value of number[i]? I know it is probably simple but I don't 'why' it does not work.

```
public int SumOfRandomNumbersWithStrings(string randomness)
{
    //Get the value of each index in the array
    string number = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < randomness.Length; i++)
    {
        number[i] = randomness[i];
    }
    //temporarily one until I finish the algorithm
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: The indexer only has a get accessor, no set accessor. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why the following code is giving me an error when I try to set the value of number[i]

Because strings in C# are immutable.

Arrays of characters are mutable, though, so you can do this:

```
char number[] = new char[randomness.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < randomness.Length; i++)
{
     number[i] = randomness[i];
}
string numStr = new string(number);
//temporarily one until I finish the algorithm
return 1;
```

The most common way of building strings in C# is by using the [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class. It lets you change the content of the string by appending, removing, or replacing characters inside the string.

Comment: That's what it was, duh. I forgot, that's why we have StringBuilders. Thanks dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 1):

Because `number` is empty string. Use concatenation operator instead:

```
number = number + randomness[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, well if you're trying to perform string concatenation let's change it to this:

```
public int SumOfRandomNumbersWithStrings(string randomness) 
{ 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    //Get the value of each index in the array 
    for (int i = 0; i < randomness.Length; i++) 
    { 
        sb.Append(randomness[i]);
    } 

    //temporarily one until I finish the algorithm 
    return 1; 
}
```

However, if you are trying to build an array out of `number` then let's change it to this:

```
public int SumOfRandomNumbersWithStrings(string randomness) 
{ 
    //Get the value of each index in the array 
    char[] number = new char[randomness.Length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < randomness.Length; i++) 
    { 
        number[i] = randomness[i]; 
    } 

    //temporarily one until I finish the algorithm 
    return 1; 
}
```

Comment: Also, for your first example, you would want to use a stringbuilder.

Comment: Thanks @Servy, I've updated my answer. I apparently posted a bit hastely, my apologies.